# What is the difference between Transform.RotateAround(point,axis,angle); and Transform.RotateAround(axis,angle)

Tags: unity-game-engine

What I understand is -

```
transform.RotateAround(point,axis,angle);
```

This rotates the transform from point along the axis by the given angle,

but then what does the following statement do

```
transform.RotateAround(axis,angle);
```

Are the following 2 statements equivalent???

```
transform.RotateAround(transform.position,axis,angle); and        transform.RotateAround(axis,angle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As weird as this seems I believe the difference between the two is as follows

```
transform.RotateAround(Point, axis, angle);
```

The above take radians to perform transform

```
transform.RotateAround(axis, angle);
```

The above takes radians to rotate around transform.position

The two parameter version used to take degrees instead of radians but some claim this has changed, though may not be updated in documentation as of yet.

So basically your last statement about their equalities should be correct yes.

Here's a source from unity that I used as well: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/181575/transformrotatearoundvector3-axis-float-angle-what.html

Comment: So the inconsistency i was getting was caused because the units of angle in both function is different(even though they appear similar),  this seems weird

Comment: If you called both versions on the bottom of your question with the same values (in degrees) and got wacky results from the 2 parameter version, than maybe it is still taking radians instead of degrees. try calling them both in a way to expect the same results. call the first and second using degrees and compare, if the results from the 2 param version are way off then try calling it with radians instead. They either both use degrees or the 2 param version uses radians and the first one (3 param version) uses degrees according to the link I posted